# How to install composer packages in different directories

Tags: composer-php

I have installed Composer on Ubuntu server using the `global` command. I have two folders named folder1 and folder2; both of them have their own composer.json files.

I want to install a package in only a folder. What happens after I edit the required composer.json file and I run `composer install`?

Comment: Have you tried it? If so, did something happen that you didn't want, or don't understand? If not, be brave, what's the worst that could happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dependencies will be installed into the current project directory.

When you run `composer install`, Composer will read the `composer.json` file from the current directory and then resolve the dependencies you defined and finally install them into a `vendor` subfolder.

See https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install

---

```
folder1
|- composer.json        // <-- dependency "VendorA/PackageA"
|- vendor
   |- composer
   |- VendorA           // <-- lands here after "composer install"
      |- PackageA

folder2
|- composer.json        // <-- dependency "VendorB/PackageB"
|- vendor
   |- composer
   |- VendorB           // <-- lands here after "composer install"
      |- PackageB
```